# Is there a way to insert a checkbox in a cell, similtar to `requireValueInList` method?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

According to GAS documentation, we can use this methods to insert a dropdownlist in a sheet cell:

```
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['Yes', 'No'], false).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to insert not a dropdown list, but dropdown a checkbox list in cell, in a similar fashion of `requireValueInList` when some trigger is used (eg, when the first cell of that row is edited).

Comment: I'm afraid the answer ils no...

Comment: Hi, @Sergeinsas, I'm enjoying reading your book on GAS! (though I have almost no time for read and weekend programming at these days...) So, the only alternative would be create a checkbox in a GUI upon the spreadsheet. Could you put your comment as an answer so I could choose it as an answer? (since it answered me, despite the answer be no)

Comment: Thanks for telling me that ! (I had so many bad reviews on that book that I was a bit discouraged I admit...) and thanks for the suggestion but I guess it's not really worth 15 points just to write a "no" !! (sorry for the late answer, just thought I did but actually I didn't ;-) btw, you could close the question by answering it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placing checkboxes in Google Sheets using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466080/placing-checkboxes-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SergeInsas said "I'm afraid the answer ils no...". So my alternative is to create a pop up checkbox list.